# How to filter with Array#filter()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting info from an API, and i want to filter some results:

This is my code to consume the API:

```
function listData() {
    $http.get('/api/Invoices?')
        .then(function(data) {
            $scope.list = data.data.Response;
    });
}
```

Then, with ng-repeat, i feed a list:

```
<tr ng-repeat="info in list">
                <th>{{info.Id}}</th>
                <th>{{info.Name}}</a></th>
                <th>{{info.value}}</th>
                <th>{{info.FiscalFolio}}</th>
</tr>
```

I want to filter for Id when the API is consumed. Someone sugest me to use Array#filter(), but i cannot make it work. This is my test, but i'm not sure is right:

```
function listData() {
    $http.get('/api/Invoices?')
        .then(function(data){
            $scope.list = data.data.Response;

            var pool = $scope.list;

            var ajax = pool.filter(function(xavier) {
                return xavier.StatusId === 1;                
            }); 
        });     
}
```

I've got two questions:

1. Is correct the way i'm working with the filter?
2. Did i need to put the variable on the html view?

Can you help me with an example?

Comment: [The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). So, your `$scope.list` still contains unfiltered array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filter()` returns a new array. Just filter the `Response` array as you assign it to `$scope.list` if you don't care about any of the other data

```
$scope.list = data.data.Response.filter(function(xavier){
     return xavier.StatusId === 1;
});
```

If you need to store the Response array you can assign it to another variable for using another filter on it later on